# Overloaded parent class fields Python

Tags: python

there are some code, but I cant understand why it is working in this way:

```
class A(object):
    first = 20
    second = 30


class B(A):
    first = 21
    second = 31

    def mix(A):
        print(A.second)

var = B()

var.mix()
```

and the output is 31, but I expected 30

Comment: Did you mean to indent `mix` so that it's part of class `B`? Because that would explain why this is happening.

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? If `mix` is *inside* `B`, note that, despite being named `A`, the argument will be the instance of `B` (conventionally named `self`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`first` and `second` are *class attributes* of `A`, and are inherited from `A` then overridden in `B`. This, I think, is what you were expecting.

```
>>> class A(object):
    first = 20
    second = 30


>>> class B(A):
    first = 21
    second = 31

    def mix(A):
        print(A.second)


>>> A.first
20
>>> A.second
30
>>> B.first
21
>>> B.second
31
```

The reason you are surprised is that you have named the first argument to `B.mix`, which is *always the instance itself* and conventionally named `self`, `A`. Inside the `mix` method, therefore, that argument (an instance of `B`) is *"shadowing"* the class `A`. If we change both to `self` you will see the same behaviour (and it will perhaps be clearer *why* that's happening):

```
>>> class B(A):
    first = 21
    second = 31

    def mix(self):
        print(self.second)


>>> b = B()
>>> b.mix()
31
```

Now if we retain the conventional `self` argument name but *change the name inside to `A`*, you will no longer be shadowing the class, and see the original value of the class attribute:

```
>>> class B(A):
    first = 21
    second = 31

    def mix(self):
        print(A.second)


>>> b = B()
>>> b.mix()
30
```